# Client wont send Data without ending the session

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm trying to create a basic C# client to connect to my Java Server however I'm getting a problem as to where the data is not being sent by the client unless the Stream is ended.

Here's my C# Code

```
        Client = new TcpClient();
        Client.Connect(address, port);

        Stream = Client.GetStream();
        DataIN = new StreamReader(Stream);
        DataOUT = new StreamWriter(Stream);

        DataOUT.Write("Hello World");
        DataOUT.Flush();

        Client.Close();
```

This successfully sends "Hello World" to the server, however if I do not use the line

```
Client.Close();
```

It will not, this is causing issues, simply because a client that lasts for no more than a single data-send wont do me any good. I have a loop setup in the client under this to keep it alive while the client is connected.. However after using Client.Close() the client is obviously no longer connected.

Help?

Comment: How are you reading the stream on server, can we see?

Comment: Is the server expecting a newline? Try `DataOUT.WriteLine("Hello World");`